# Gradle: Importing plugins class from applied script

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, import

I'm running a weird behaviour with gradle (multiproject wrapper):

my root `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    // Docker plugin
    id "de.gesellix.docker" version "2017-10-05T23-00-11"
}
```

a script helper `java-docker.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "de.gesellix.docker"

import de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerBuildTask
import de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerTask

task prepareDockerImage(type: DockerBuildTask, dependsOn: war) {
    // Task here
}
```

and my application `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "${gradleDirPath}/java-docker.gradle"
apply from: "${gradleDirPath}/java-webapp.gradle"

dependencies {
    // App dependencies
}
```

when running `./gradlew help` I run into :

> unable to resolve class de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerTask
>   @ line 6, column 1.
>        import de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerTask

and

> unable to resolve class
>   de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerBuildTask    @ line 5, column 1.
>        import de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerBuildTask

I've tried to remove the `apply from: "${gradleDirPath}/java-docker.gradle"` from app `build.gradle` and to directly apply plugin and imports directly in app `build.gradle`, and **this is working** as expected.

Any idea why the import from an applied script fails ?

Comment: Could you please provide a directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the new plugin mechanism does not add the **plugin classes** to scripts classpath. They are only available to root `build.gradle` and projects `build.gradle`.

So I had to go back to the old buildscript mechanism

my `java-docker.gradle` now looks like:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
   classpath "de.gesellix:gradle-docker-plugin:2017-10-05T20-48-17"
  }
}

apply plugin: de.gesellix.gradle.docker.DockerPlugin

import de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerBuildTask
import de.gesellix.gradle.docker.tasks.DockerTask
```

I've also removed the plugins entry for docker in my root `build.gradle`

***Edit for [opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal)***

my directory structure looks like :

```
.
├── buildsystem
│  ├── build.gradle
│  ├── gradle
│  │  └── java-docker.gradle
│  ├── gradle.properties
│  ├── gradlew
│  ├── gradlew.bat
│  ├── README.md
│  └── settings.gradle
└── myapp
  ├── build.gradle
  └── settings.gradle
```